# easy animation delay not working

Tags: jquery, css, animation, delay

I'm new to jQuery. I'm using [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and just want to add delay in the animation so I tried this:

```
$('#fadeInRight').delay(20000).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: can you provide samples of your code? Maybe a fiddle showig the problem?

Comment: did you try the other way round? `$('#fadeInRight').addClass('animated fadeInRight').delay(20000);`

Comment: Surely one of the questions you found suggested to use setTimeout to delay addClass

Comment: I'd go with Pranav's answer, using one "setTimeout" is a lot cleaner than specifying a bunch of CSS stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)**

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#fadeInRight').addClass('animated fadeInRight')},20000);
```

Comment: I know this works, but I've never understood why jQuery's ".delay" doesn't.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 2):

The [github page](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) states another way to add a delay, no jQuery needed:

---

```
#yourElement {
    -vendor-animation-duration: 3s;
    -vendor-animation-delay: 2s;
    -vendor-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

}

Note: be sure to replace "vendor" in the CSS with the applicable vendor prefixes (webkit, moz, etc)

---

Comment: Please note that this approach is only supported in IE10 and above.